# How to add a LIMIT to a user-generated sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have built a query editor where a user can enter in a query. However, it needs to limit the user's entry to 1000 results, otherwise the user could enter in something like :

```
SELECT * FROM mybigtable
```

It could try and download 1 billion results.

What would be the best way to enforce a limit? The first approach I thought of was to do:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    user-query
) x LIMIT 1000
```

However, this would execute the entire query (and could take forever) before doing the actual limit. What would be the best way to enforce a strict limit on the user's sql input?

Comment: I would hope that the query optimiser would rewrite that as `user-query LIMIT MIN(user-limit, 1000)`...

Comment: @Nick it doesn't when I try on a large table in mysql: `select * from (select * from main_item) x limit 100`

Comment: your approach is correct. your query only selects 1000 rows. thats all

Comment: @Simonare I understand theoretically it's correct, but I don't want the end user waiting 20 minutes when they issue a query to return 1000 results if it's downloading the entire table in the sub select statement.

Comment: it does not download. DBMS systems are intelligent in this manner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

I don’t think that there is generic solution for this.

Wrapping the user query in a `SELECT * FROM ... LIMIT 1000` statement is attractive but ;

- there are edge cases where it can produce invalid SQL, for example if the user query contains a CTE (the `WITH` clause must be placed at the very beginning of the query)
- while it will happily limit the number of rows returned to the user, it will not prevent the database from scanning the entire resultset

The typical solution for the second use case is to filter rows according to an autoincremented  integer column (usually the primary key of your table). But that’s even harder to make generic.

To make it short : manipulating SQL at distance is tricky : if you want a complete solution for your use case, get yourself a real query builder (or at least a sql parser).

Comment: thanks. Could this be done using something like `sqlparse`? If so, would you want to show an example of how this could be done and I'll accept your answer?

Comment: @DavidL ... yes sqlparse is a good option if you are using python. This is beyond the scope of your original post but there are plenty of resources available to learn, eg [this recent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031053/determine-if-a-sql-statement-starts-with-the-word-select).

Comment: sure, I'll ask another question more specific to it.

Comment: are there any sql parsers you can suggest that allow manipulating a query? It looks like sqlparse is read-only.