# Determine if a sql statement starts with the word SELECT

Tags: python, mysql, sql, regex

I am trying to do some basic validation on an input SQL string. I want to make sure the first word of the query is `SELECT` or else I'll raise an error. Here are some examples:

```
1) yes
SELECT * FROM table

2) no
# SELECT * FROM table;
DROP TABLE table;

3) no
   /* SELECT * FROM 
   TABLE */ DROP TABLE table;

4) yes
# here is a comment
SELECT * FROM table

5) yes
/* here is a
comment */ SELECT * FROM table
```

And various others. Perhaps this is more of a regex solution or string.replace. But what would be a good way to see if a SQL SELECT statement has been entered?

Comment: Perhaps a safer solution, or something in addition to this would be to restict the access rights of the database user you are using to connect to the database so that only selects would be allowed..

Comment: @alecxe that's the first option, yes. This is the second option (more useful for testing.)

Comment: `sql.lower().startswith("select")`?

Comment: @Selcuk right but that's incorrect. What if the first line is a comment?

Comment: I don't see how this protects against anything. Won't SQL still support deleting all records after a SELECT in the same string?

Comment: @roganjosh could you give an example of the statement that could do that?

Comment: @DavidL Yes, that's why I didn't post it as an answer. I was oversimplifying. A proper SQL parser such as https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/ is the way to go.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table; DELETE TABLE  - Starts with select, but two commands on a single line

Comment: @Selcuk that sounds like the best approach. Would you want to post an answer of how that could be used and I'll accept it?

Comment: @roganjosh, That's a good reason to avoid executing SQL with the multi-query API. Just execute one SQL statement at a time (that's the default), and you won't be vulnerable to `SELECT ... ; DROP TABLE ...` attacks. I was told by the former engineering director of MySQL, "there's no good reason for multi-query to exist."

Comment: You can `SELECT MyArbitraryStoredFunction() FROM DUAL` and the function can do arbitrary DML.

Comment: @BillKarwin but checking a string for starting with SELECT let's that right through. That isn't accounted for here?

Comment: Yes, I'm not advocating regular expression based security. :-)

Comment: My comment was for your former one; nothing is stopping multiquery from what we see

Comment: Multi-query is an API option. If you don't explicitly enable multi-query at the connection level, it won't work. It's disabled by default. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't know that for MYSQL:)

Comment: I just thought the Python DB connector *might* enable multi-query, but I found this post that says it does not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518677/mysqldb-cursor-execute-cant-run-multiple-queries

Comment: @Billkarwin that's an interesting point, actually, because I've seen quite a few answers that make use of it without stating it's off by default. I'm glad I had this discussion to cement it as "no", I've never tried it and it was one of things at the back of my mind, overtaken by other issues. Thanks for your research and clarifications.

Comment: I think the ubiquitous https://xkcd.com/327 makes people think multi-query is the primary risk of SQL injection. But SQL injection can do lots of mischief without multi-query.

Comment: @BillKarwin... i believe consideration was given to supporting multiple statements in pymysql `execute()` , and whether to adopt/copy the `executescript()` nonstandard extension of other libraries. But that was several years ago, pre DB-API 2.0. Disabling multiquery does close the door to some nefarious SQL Injections, but that is by no means the only door. (And I concur, regex is *not* a suitable tool for doing SQL validation; some simple regex can be used to sanitize (check the sanity) of user supplied input.... but not as protection against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a proper tool for the job - [`sqlparse` SQL parser](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest), get the first statement object and check if it's of a `SELECT` type:

```
In [1]: import sqlparse

In [2]: queries = [
   ...:     "SELECT * FROM table",
   ...:     """
   ...:     # SELECT * FROM table;
   ...:     DROP TABLE table;
   ...:     """,
   ...:     """/* SELECT * FROM 
   ...:    TABLE /* DROP table table;""",
   ...:    """
   ...:    # here is a comment
   ...:    SELECT * FROM table
   ...:    """
   ...: ]

In [3]: def is_select(query):
             first_statement = next((token for token in sqlparse.parse(query) if isinstance(token, sqlparse.sql.Statement)), None) 
             if first_statement:
                 return first_statement.get_type() == 'SELECT'

In [4]: for query in queries:
    ...:     print(query, is_select(query))

    SELECT * FROM table 
    True

    # SELECT * FROM table;
    DROP TABLE table;
    False

   /* SELECT * FROM 
   TABLE /* DROP table table; 
   False

   # here is a comment
   SELECT * FROM table
   True
```

Comment: thanks. Would there be any difference in checking it in all statements or just the first statement?

Comment: @DavidL you could probably check all just to be safe. Better yet on top of that disable multiple queries per execute for your db driver if it’s enabled. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Although regexes and other text based tricks can be employed, a proper SQL parser such as https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/ is the way to go. For example:

```
import sqlparse
statements = sqlparse.parse(my_evil_sql)
for statement in statements:
  if statement.get_type() != "SELECT":
    raise Exception("Non-select statement encountered!")
```

Note that `get_type()` ignores whitespaces and comments at the beginning of the statement.