# Using sqlparse to add a dynamic sql limit

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Is it possible to add a limit  of N in `sqlparse`? For example, suppose a user enters in the following three queries (using 1000 as the limit in the examples):

```
1) Reformat if limit > 1000
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1e10
==> SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1000

2) Reformat if no limit
SELECT * FROM mytable
==> SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1000

3) Ignore if a limit <= 1000 already applied
SELECT * FROM mytable
==> [ ok ]
```

Additionally, is `sqlparse` able to modify the limit according to database engine? For example, the `limit` in mysql is different than the `top` in mssql. Examples:

```
MySQL:      SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1000
PostgreSQL: SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1000
Oracle:     SELECT * FROM table WHERE rownum <= 1000
MsSQL:      SELECT TOP 1000 FROM table
```

Or, if it's not possible to do in `sqlparse`, are there other libraries where this may be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031053/determine-if-a-sql-statement-starts-with-the-word-select are we doing all your work for you?

Comment: Did you try to apply learning from previous question to here?